# Need help creating a java program that prints a table of contents from a book

Tags: java

I'm supposed to write a java program, which prints a table of contents, using the following data structure:

```
public class TocEntry 
{ 
    // Specify the needed methods 
    private String chapter; 
    private int page; 
}
```

And the following defined in my driver class:

```
public final int TOCSIZE = 100; 
TocEntry toc[] = new TocEntry[TOCSIZE]; 
int toc_curlen = 0; //The toc_curlen is intended to keep track of the number of chapters entered by the user and it can be used as an index into the array of TocEntry objects.
```

Next, I'm supposed to develop the necessary code, in my TocEntry class, to read in a chapter name and page number until “`**`” is entered.  From this, my output should look like this:

> My Story Starts.......................1
>
> Growing up...........................35
>
> Conquering the World........103

This is supposed to be my sample run using a driver called useTocEntry

> Enter chapter title: Camelot
>
> Enter starting page number: 1
>
> Enter chapter title: King Arthur's Court
>
> Enter starting page number: 3
>
> Enter chapter title: Knights of the Table Round
>
> Enter starting page number: 8
>
> Enter chapter title: Sir Dinadan the Humorist
>
> Enter starting page number: 12
>
> Enter chapter title: An Inspiration
>
> Enter starting page number: 14
>
> Enter chapter title: The Eclipse
>
> Enter starting page number: 23
>
> Enter chapter title: A Postscript by Clarence
>
> Enter starting page number: 274
>
> Enter chapter title: `**`
>
> Camelot..........................................1
>
> King Arthur's Court.........................3
>
> Knights of the Table Round............8
>
> Sir Dinadan the Humorist..............12
>
> An Inspiration................................14
>
> The Eclipse...................................23
>
> A Postscript by Clarence.............274

This is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class TocEntry {
    public TocEntry() { // Default Constructor
        chapter = "";
        page = 0;
    }

    public TocEntry(String c, int p) { // 2 Argument Constructor
        chapter = c;
        page = p;
    }

    public String getChapter() { //getChapter() and getPage() are accessor methods
        return chapter;
    }

    public int getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setChapter(String title) { ////setChapter() and setPage() are mutator methods
        chapter = title;
    }

    public void setPage(int numPage) {
        page = numPage;
    }

    private String chapter; 
    private int page;

    public String toString() { // toString method to print out contents
        return  chapter + "**" + page;
    }
}// End of class TocEntry
```

And this is my driver class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class useToEntry {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of contents you would like to display:   ");
        int TOC_NUM = input.nextInt();
        final int TOCSIZE = 100;
        TocEntry toc[] = new TocEntry[TOCSIZE]; 
        int toc_curlen = 0; // The toc_curlen is intended to keep track of the number 
                        // of chapters entered by the user and it can be used as an
                        // index into the array of TocEntry objects. 
        for(int i = 0; i < TOC_NUM; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter chapter title: ");
            String ch = input.next();     
            System.out.print("Enter starting page number: ");
            int y = input.nextInt();
        }// End of for loop
    } // End of main method

}// End of class useTocEntry
```

I need help, especially to create a method that aligns the `**` with the chapter title and the page number. Any help or advice on my code would be appreciated.

Comment: This looks like the skeleton code of an assignment to me... Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: don't just say, "I need help", tell us what stop you finish this course work. this is a typical colleague assignment, very little chance people just do it for you. you need work hard on this first. I believe you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

So. What you need to know the maximum possible `String` length of all the chapters.

This is easiest achieved by monitoring the text been entered during your input stage...something like...

```
int maxChapterLength = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < TOC_NUM; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter chapter title: ");
    String ch = input.next();     
    maxChapterLength = Math.max(ch.length(), maxChapterLength);
    System.out.print("Enter starting page number: ");
    int y = input.nextInt();
}// End of for loop
```

From this, you can then determine the required padding between the chapter name and the chapter number

Something like...

```
public static String pad(String sValue, int iMinLength) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(iMinLength);
    sb.append(sValue);

    while (sb.length() < iMinLength) {
        sb.append(".");
    }

    return sb.toString();

}
```

From there you simply need to send the info to the screen...something like...

```
System.out.println(pad(toc[index].getChapter(), maxChapterLength + 2) + toc[index].getPage());
```

Now, having looked at you're code, you have a bunch of other problems, but I leave it to you to identify.