# Creating a Java Program that outputs a table of contents

Tags: java, loops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need help creating a java program that prints a table of contents from a book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455148/need-help-creating-a-java-program-that-prints-a-table-of-contents-from-a-book)

I'm supposed to create a program that outputs a table of contents. Let me give you guys a background of my assignment. The user is supposed to enter a chapter title and a starting page number in a loop, until the user enters 4 asterisks for the chapter title. After the user enters the 4 asterisks, I'm supposed to print out the output, something like

King Arthur's Court.............................3

Knights of the Table Round... ............8

Sir Dinadan the Humorist..................12

I think I have most of my coding right. In my test program, I created a while loop that allows the user to enter a chapter title and a starting page number. This loop will terminate when the user enters 4 asterisks for the chapter title. But, where I'm stuck is after my while loop, to generate the output after the user enters the asterisks. Instead of having the table of contents displayed, I'm getting an output. I tried a for loop to print out the title, dots, and page number, but it only displays asterisks. I think that the loop is wrong.

Here's my code so far:

```
// My Table of Contents class
public class TocEntry
{

public TocEntry(String title, int page) // 2 Argument Constructor
{
           chapterTitle = title;
           startPage = page;
}


public String toString() // toString method to print out chapter title,
                         // given dots, and start page
{
    String temp = "" + startPage;
    int numDots = 60 - (temp.length()+ chapterTitle.length());

    String toc_out = chapterTitle;
    for(int i = 0; i < numDots; i++)
       toc_out=toc_out +".";
       toc_out= toc_out + startPage;
    return toc_out;
}


private String chapterTitle; 
private int startPage;


    }// End of class TocEntry

// My Test program
import java.util.Scanner;
public class useToEntry {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    final int TOCSIZE = 100;// Max size of TOC
    TocEntry toc[] = new TocEntry[TOCSIZE];
    int toc_curlen = 0;// The toc_curlen is intended to keep track of the number 
                       // of chapters entered by the user

    System.out.print("Enter chapter title: ");
    String chapterTitle = input.next();

    while(!"****".equals(chapterTitle))
    {
       System.out.print("Enter starting page number: ");
       int page = input.nextInt();

       System.out.print("Enter chapter title: ");
       chapterTitle= input.next();

       toc [toc_curlen] = new TocEntry(chapterTitle,page);
       toc_curlen = toc_curlen++;

    }// End of while loop

       for (int line = 0; line < toc_curlen; line++)
       {
         System.out.println(chapterTitle.toString());
       }// End of for loop
  }// End of main method

}// End of class useToEntry
```

Can anyone please help me correct my loop to generate my output. I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Didn't we already do this?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455148/need-help-creating-a-java-program-that-prints-a-table-of-contents-from-a-book/12456026#12456026

Comment: So vote to close as duplicate?

Comment: @Marko the [tag:homework] tag is dead.  No longer use it.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Thanks, didn't know that. Why is it dead?

Comment: @Marko  I don't know, but it has been unpopular with people on meta for a while now.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

The line

```
toc_curlen = toc_curlen++;
```

will cause `toc_curlen` never to increment. You can just use the increment operator on its own:

```
toc_curlen++;
```

The very first time you use

```
String chapterTitle = input.next();
```

you never assign it to your `TocEntry` array `toc`, so this chapter will never be shown.

You are printing the variable `chapterTitle` repeatedly in the display loop - you should print your `TocEntry` here:

```
for (int line = 0; line < toc_curlen; line++) {
   System.out.println(toc[line].toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code a bit. First, when you want to put together a lots of strings consider using a StringBuilder instead of the + operator. Strings are immutable, so every time you use a + operator, a new String is created, and the concatenated two are going into the garbage:

```
public String toString()
{
    String temp = Integer.toString(startPage);
    int numDots = 60 - (temp.length() + chapterTitle.length());

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(chapterTitle);
    for (int i = 0; i < numDots; i++)
        sb.append('.');

    sb.append(startPage);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

But the problem was, that you didn't iterate through your array, only printed the current chapter title:

```
for (int line = 0; line < toc_curlen; line++)
{
    System.out.println(chapterTitle.toString());
}
```

Here is a "better" version of the main() function:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //its much easier to work with lists
    List<TocEntry> list = new ArrayList<TocEntry>();
    String chapterTitle = "";

    //sorry for the while(true), but it looks easier doing everything 
    //inside the loop instead ofdoing half the job outside, half inside of it.
    while (true)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter chapter title: ");
        chapterTitle = input.next();
        if("****".equals(chapterTitle)) break;

        System.out.print("Enter starting page number: ");
        int page = input.nextInt();

        list.add(new TocEntry(chapterTitle, page));
    }

    for (TocEntry entry : list)
        System.out.println(entry);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks very much like homework...
Well, first the line `toc_curlen = toc_curlen++;` should be shortened to `toc_curlen++;` (think about it why).

Your real problem is in that for loop you are using for printing. Look exactly what you are printing, and you will spot it.